# Android App widget not updating

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

I've seen several other questions about widgets not updating but all of them was because updatePeriodMillis was configured to a value less than 30min and I've set mine to 1 hour and been checking for several hours now.

I've started a separate project from my actual widget project just to test the update and I'm getting nowhere.

The widget simply updates a TextView with currentTimeMillis().

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <receiver android:name="TestWidget" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:resource="@xml/widget" android:name="android.appwidget.provider"/>
    </receiver>
```

widget.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
     android:minHeight="40dp"
     android:minWidth="250dp"
     android:updatePeriodMillis="3600000" >
 </appwidget-provider>
```

everything loads fine on the 1st call, but onUpdate is never called again.

Any suggestions?

edit:

TestWidget.class only overrides onUpdate

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        // Inflate the layout
        RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget);
        v.setTextViewText(R.id.text1, Double.toString(Math.random()));
        v.setTextViewText(R.id.text2,
                Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        // Update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], v);

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the class you are using to extend the appwidget provider? (TestWidget)

Comment: done. Added it to the post. As I said, that's a test only, just to see the update feature. The actual thing is doing much more work, but not even that simple ons is working. ps.: Running on a Galaxy Nexus Stock JB

Comment: Do you override the onReceive method in your code? If so have you got the following within it:                            super.onReceive(context, intent);

Comment: No. Only onUpdate() is overridden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to apologise to the community for the unnecessary question as it seems in the end that either my phone was acting up (considering that I reboot the thing) or I was simply being a bit inpatient.

As it seems, it really takes several several hours for the onUpdate to start being called by the framework. On the past 3 hours (I was sleeping before that) I can see the updated coming quite consistently.

I didn't delete the question, just in case someone have the same problem, YOU REALLY HAVE TO WAIT!

Thanks.

Comment: I was just about to say I have copied your code into my project and it worked >D so I can confirm the code works.